# Как работает конструкция f'{n:,}'?

Tags: python

Писал код на codewars и нашел то, что сложно загуглить)

писал код который из `'10000000'` дает `'10,000,000'`

ну так вот, в solve, я нашел такую конструкцию: `f'{n:,}'` и не совсем понял как она работает, буду очень благодарен, если обьясните ;)

Comment: Погуглите про `f-строки в питоне`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> num = 10000000
>>> print(f"{num:,}")
10,000,000
```

- Часть после двоеточия - это спецификатор формата.
- Запятая - это желаемый разделитель, поэтому `f"{num:_}"` вместо запятой используются подчеркивания.

С этим методом можно использовать только символы `«,»` и `«_»`.

Это эквивалент использования `format(num, ",")` более старых версий python3.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-formatted-output/#the-group-subcomponent

Comment: Эквивалент не так написан

Comment: @eri буду рад критике